# Recoding data into files N samples each with GNU Radio

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I'm recording data with USRP X310 using GNU Radio. I need to record and process data for days (possibly weeks) non-stop at a very high sampling rate, so I cannot store all the data on HDD, I need to process it on a fly. I want to cut continuous stream of data into chunks N samples each and process these chunks with a python program I have. One way of doing this, as I see, is to store each chunk into a file on HDD on a fly, so I can simultaneously access it with another program and process it.

Is there a way of doing this in GNU Radio?

Thank you!

Comment: The answer to your question "is there a way of doing this in GNU Radio" is "yes, that's **exactly** what GNU Radio is for". Um, have you read the intro to GNU Radio (the 0. chapter) on https://tutorials.gnuradio.org ?

Comment: Yes, I've read tutorial, I have everything installed and configured. I can record a stream of data into one file, there is no problem with that. What I don't get is how to make a series of files so GRC, for instance, would put first 10^6 samples in file 1, next 10^6 into file 2 etc. I can't find any loops in GRC, which is what I would use in python for the purpose. And I can't just put GRC generated code for recording data into single file into my program, since every time I run the code, it takes time to start a measurement, and a big chunk of signal is lost.

Comment: That's also possible, but the purpose of GNU Radio is to process chunks of data. So you'd just put your code into a GNU Radio block

Comment: GNU Radio has tag system, so one option is to tag every N-th sample and use that to trigger opening and recording a new file. However I don't see a clear way to do that with existing blocks. And I couldn't find a good tutorial on tags in GNU Radio. I can probably figure out how to write whatever blocks I need and build a program from a scratch. I just want to know if there is a simpler way to do what I want using existing blocks. And how I could do it if there is one.